# How to find anchor without a specifc class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, anchor

I want to remove anchors with href contains "#tab" **without a specific css class "atitleTabs"**  from some specific divs whose Id contains "tab". I have tried the following code it didn't work for me.

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $('div ul li a').filter(function () {
        if (!$('div ul li a').hasClass('atitleTabs')) {
            alert('Got Anchor without the particlauar class');
            alert($('div ul li a').attr('href'));
        } else {
            alert('Got Anchor with class');
        }

    });

});
```

How can i do it, please help me, how can i achieve my goal.

Comment: Question title and content is not in sync. What is the exact problem? EDIT: You should look into https://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: @Satpal sorry i have missed some of information, please read the updated question'

Comment: You can use `$('div ul li a').not('.atitleTabs')`

Comment: I have already done that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`attribute contains selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to achieve what you want,

```
$('div[id*="tab"] a[href*="#tab"]:not(".atitleTabs")').remove();
```

or just try the samething with `.filter()`

```
$('div[id*="tab"] a[href*="#tab"])').filter(':not(".atitleTabs")').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**:

```
$('[id*="tab"]').find('[href*="#tab"]').remove();
```

Comment: we are using attr - contains selector, may be elements rather than div might contain an id which contains `tab`.. right..?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("[id*=tab]").find("[href*='#tab']").remove();
```

You can use attribute selector `*` for this purpose.

If you want to use `startwith` clause you can use `^`.

If you want to use `endswith` clause, use `$`