# How to find anchor with a specifc class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, filter, anchor

I want to remove anchors with href contains "#tab" with a specific css class "atitleTabs" from some specific divs whose Id contains "tab". I have tried the following code it didn't work for me.

```
 $('div[id*="tab"] a[href*="#tab"])').hasClass(".atitleTabs").remove();
```

please help me, how can i achieve my goal

Comment: Use `$('div[id*="tab"] a[href*="#tab"])').filter(".atitleTabs").remove()`, __Can I downvote your question__ as you have answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954991/how-to-find-anchor-without-a-specifc-class-using-jquery

Comment: @Satpal both conditions are different, i think..
i have already tried the above you provided.. it didn't work for me

Comment: Allthough I have not downvoted, But disagree that both conditions are different, One is has class and second one not has class only thats different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a boolean value, so your method will fail with an error

```
$('div[id*="tab"] a.atitleTabs[href*="#tab"]').remove();
```

or

```
$('div[id*="tab"] a[href*="#tab"])').filter(".atitleTabs").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('div[id*="tab"] a.atitleTabs[href*="#tab"])').remove();
```

Comment: [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a boolean value

Comment: boolean does not contains a function called `.remove()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `.hasClass()` return a boolean value, in order to chain your selector without modifying most of your code, you can use **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** instead:

```
$('div[id*="tab"] a[href*="#tab"])').filter(".atitleTabs").remove();
```

Comment: [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a boolean value